# Assigning K,V pairs to a JSON object in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json

I have a NodeJS script that takes data from a source in the form of "key, value" pairs, and I would like to put that data into a JSON object.

I am using SNMP to get the k, v pairs, where the key is the OID. I would like to then map those values onto a JSON object without having to iteratively check each OID against a known value.

The k,v pairs are stored in objects as such, and I have no flexibility over this incoming data.

```js
let pair = {
    key: "abc...",
    value: "xyz..."
}
```

I have defined the JSON object as an empty structure.

```js
let jsonObject = {
    ipaddress: "",
    network: {
        uptime: "",
        throughput: "",
        devices: ""
    }
}
```

And I iterate through my keys (`pairs` is the name of an array containing the k,v objects)

```js
for (let i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
    if (pairs[i].key == "1.2.3.4.5.6.7") jsonObject.ipaddress = pairs[i].value;
    if (pairs[i].key == "2.3.4.5.6.7.8") jsonObject.network.uptime = pairs[i].value;
    if (pairs[i].key == "3.4.5.6.7.8.9") jsonObject.network.devices = pairs[i].value;
}
```

I would like to know if there is any way to simplify this, as I have around 200 keys to process (the above code is simply an example), and it doesn't seem particularly well optimised for me to iterate over every possible key.

EDIT: The jsonObject is a lot more complex than shown here, with lots of layers and the names of the keys do not match up 1:1 with the json object property names as shown.

EDIT 2: This seems like an odd situation, I know.
For example, I want to take the K,V input:

```
Key            Value
1.2.3.4.5.6    "10.0.0.1"
2.3.4.5.6.7    "3 Days 14 Hours 32 Minutes"
3.4.5.6.7.8    "1.1.1.1"
```

And convert it to a dissimilarly named JSON object

```js
{
    uptime: "3 Days 14 Hours 32 Minutes",
    networking: {
        ip: "10.0.0.1",
        dns: "1.1.1.1"
    }
}
```

Potentially using some form of mapping, instead of using ~200 if statements

Comment: You simplified your example... And it's ok. But does the `jsonObject` has more than only `name` and `properties` as 1st level object property?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette, sorry, yes. The jsonObject is a lot more complex than shown here, with lots of layers. Also, the names do not match up 1:1 as shown above.

Comment: `Also, the names do not match up 1:1 `... I suggest you try one of the answers below to create the object filled with values. Then, to rename some specific property names, you'll have to run a second loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) function.

```
const { name, ...properties } = pairs.reduce(
  (obj, { key, value }) => Object.assign(obj, { [key]: value }),
  {}
)

const obj = { name, properties }
```

Reduce will reduce an array into a scalar, in this case an object with all k,v pairs as fields with values on an object, starting with `{}` as a default value the merging each k,v pair 1 at a time.

[Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) will merge objects, overwriting objects on the left with the fields of keys of objects on the right.

And finally the syntax to dynamically add a key on an object literal is `{ [k]: v }`

By the way this is a useful trick for reducing the complexity of algorithms where you need to look up values in an array in a loop. Simply create an index of one array then in the loop, lookup in the index instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/he/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) for iterating and assigning the object.

```js
const jsonObject = {
     name: '',
     properties: {
           email: '',
           address: '',
           town: ''
     }
 };

const pairs = [{key: 'name',    value: 'thatsimplekid'},
               {key: 'email',   value: 'aaa@domain.com'}, 
               {key: 'town',    value: 'myTown'},
               {key: 'address', value:'123 main st' }];


pairs.forEach( ({key, value}) => 
                   jsonObject.hasOwnProperty(key) ?
                             jsonObject[key] = value : 
                             jsonObject.properties[key] = value);

console.log(jsonObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   for (let i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
      const key = pairs[i].key;
      const value = pairs[i].value;

      if (pairs[i].key == "name") {
        jsonObject[key] = value;
      } else {
        jsonObject.properties[key] = value;
      }
    }
```

After the 'name' all values goes to the properties object, so a simple if would do it